# Server sent events with spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, server-sent-events

How can I configure the spring cloud gateway to work with SSE I searched in the documentation but it only has info about web sockets.

Comment: Nothing special is needed

Comment: @spencergibb even if the connection is open for several minutes?

Comment: That is correct